# Java - how to hold and add the output of each for-loop iteration together -- store into HashMap

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, hashmap, iteration

I hava a code similar to the code below.

I want to print all iterations' output together, not separately.

Is there anybody here to help me with it?

```
HashMap<String, String> myHashMap = new HashMap <String, String>();

for (int j = 0; j < x.length(); j++) 

    int firstElement = 0;
    int secondElement = 1;
    if (myArray.length() > 0) {

        String first = myArray.get(firstElement).toString();
        String last = myArray.get(secondElement).toString();
        //System.out.println(first + " --> " + last);

        boolean a = Info.contains("xxx");
        boolean b = Info.contains("yyy");

        if( a || b ) {
            //System.out.println(first + " --> " + last);

            count++;
            myHashMap.put(first, last);                             
            System.out.println(count + "\t" + first);
            total = total + " " + first;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I can print the output for each iteration.

But I need to print all together. Is there any way to save them into a HashMap and print them all together?

Comment: What is Info? You can use StringBuilder to append the output to it after the loop finished print it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code works correctly, this is one of the possible ways:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  // Defined outside of the for loop

...

if( a || b ) {
    //System.out.println(first + " --> " + last);

    count++;
    myHashMap.put(first, last);                             
    System.out.println(count + "\t" + first);
    total = total + " " + first;
    sb.append(count).append("\t").append(first).append("\n");

}

...

System.out.println(sb.toString()); // Print out the output after the for loop.
```